# Swift, is it possible to have an IBInspectable block?

Tags: swift, uiview, ibinspectable

I have approximately 50 properties in my view that I must make inspectable.

Is there a way to do so without declaring it explicitly for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable` must be declared explicitly for each class/property you wish to show up in interface builder.

Comment: Pity : ( Thanks for the prompt reply!